# Ways to Move up and Down the dir structure in Python

Tags: python

```
#Moving up/down dir structure
print os.listdir('.')
print os.listdir('..')
print os.listdir('../..')
```

Any othe ways???  I got saving dirs before going deeper, then reassigning later.

Comment: You need to indicate what you're trying to do, because this isn't moving up or down directory hierarchies, it's merely listing the contents of various directories.  `os.chdir` is how you change directory.

Comment: basically I'm trying to write a simple program that recoursively check all the directory's in a path and deletes empty ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for name in dirs:
        try:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
        except WindowsError:
            print 'Skipping', os.path.join(root, name)
```

This will walk the file system beginning in the directory the script is run from. It deletes the empty directories at each level.

Comment: and what if you wanted to move all the files up to the root directory?

Comment: I'm just curious.   I actually got it working, but it was like 80 lines of code... lol

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are -
thre are both `os.walk` - which returns tuples with the subdirectories, and the files tehrein as
`os.path.walk`, which takes a callback function to be called for each file in a directory structure.

You can check the online help for both functions.

Comment: btw. for getting you this answer I inferred you want to do this only due to your "saving dirs before going deeper" comment. If you want just to change dirs, os.chdir is obviously the right answer.

Comment: Well I guess I was going to try to have some temporary place holders.  For example, I'll be changing between the parent and child a lot in certain methods.  I think I'll just try saving the state.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.chdir()`

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os-file-dir

Am I missing something in the question?

Answer (score 0):

> > "and what if you wanted to move all the files up to the root directory?"

You could do something like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for f in files:
        try:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, f), os.getcwd())
        except:
            print f, 'already exists in', os.getcwd()
```